# Centering text using html in jupyter notebook without vertical shift

Tags: html, markdown, jupyter

I am trying to have two words in a markdown cell in Jupyter, one word left-aligned and one word in the center. The most intuitive way to do this is `# word 1    <center> word 2 </center>`. However, the center tag also places word 2 in the vertical center of the cell, so the end result has word 1 and word 2 on different lines. Is there a way to center word 2 without this undesired effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in a jupyter cell:

```
%%html
<div>
    <span style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: left;">Word1</span>
    <span style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">Word2</span>
</div>
```

EDIT: sorry missed the markdown aspect.  For markdown remove the %%html magic, so just this:

```
<div>
    <span style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: left;">Word1</span>
    <span style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">Word2</span>
</div>
```

This works because markdown is a [subset of html](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#General-HTML).